# How do I extend a Ruby module in class context?

Tags: ruby, module, extend

I have the following Ruby script, in which class Foo includes module Baz, module Baz has a included hook to make Bar extended by the including class (Foo). I am just wondering why:

```
class << klass
  extend Bar #this doesn't work. Why?
end
```

does not work while:

```
klass.extend(Bar) works.
```

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

module Baz
  def inst_method
    puts "dude"
  end 

  module Bar
    def cls_method
      puts "Yo"
    end
  end

  class << self
    def included klass
      # klass.extend(Bar) this works, but why the other approach below doesn't?
      class << klass
        extend Bar #this doesn't work. Why?
        def hello
          puts "hello"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Baz
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.inst_method
Foo.hello
Foo.cls_method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the body of `class << klass`, `self` refers to the singleton class of `klass`, not `klass` itself, whereas in `klass.extend(Bar)`, the receiver is `klass` itself. The difference comes from there.

```
class A
end

class << A
  p self  # => #<Class:A>   # This is the singleton class of A, not A itself.
end

p A # => A     # This is A itself.
```

And since you want to apply `extend` to `klass`, doing it within the body of `class << klass` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is invoke the `extend` method on the class object (klass) not the singleton class (class << klass).

Therefore the following code doesn't work because you are invoking the `extend` method on the singleton class:

```
  class << klass
    extend Bar # doesn't work because self refers to the the singleton class of klass
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I just realized that in the singleton class, I need to use include Bar instead of extend Bar.